# Orcalize Query not working

Tags: oracles

```
function getRandomNumber() public payable {
    require(msg.value >= 0.000175 ether); // 175,000 gas * 1 Gwei = 0.000175 ETH

   bytes32 queryId = oraclize_query("URL", "json(https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts).title", "{title: 'foo',body: 'bar',userId: 1}");

//   oraclize_query( 
//       "nested", 
//       "[URL] ['json(https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/invoke).result.random[\"data\"]', '\\n{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"method\": \"generateSignedIntegers\", \"params\": { \"apiKey\": \"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\", \"n\": 1, \"min\": 1, \"max\": 1000, \"replacement\": true, \"base\": 10 }, \"id\": 14215 }']"
//     );   

    LogOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was sent, standing by for the answer..");

    validIds[queryId] = true;
}
```

When I try to use the first query it doesn't work and the result is not updated but the commented one works just fine. I don't know whats wrong with it.

This the callback function

```
    function __callback(bytes32 queryId, string result, bytes proof) public {
        require(msg.sender == oraclize_cbAddress());

        require(validIds[queryId]);

        // randomNumber = parseInt(result); 

        title = result;

        LogResultReceived(result); 

        validIds[queryId] = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

json(https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts).0.title

Also, you can test your queries here: https://app.provable.xyz/home/test_query